# How can I find a specific position of a character from a line of code I'm evaluating

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do in input file stream a text document, then evaluate each character by displaying information to the user and for the use of the rest of my code. The only question I have is, if I do a loop like

```
myIn >> ch;
while (myIn) 
{
   //proceeds with code
}
```

That reads from file input stream, how can I find the line number and position of that character I just read in?

For example on a text document like this

```
Hello
How are you
```

I want to read in H, and say that H was found in line one, position 0. Continuing, read in w, found in position 1 line 2. Without grabbing an entire string line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get the line number and character position is to count them yourself:

```
char c;
unsigned int character_count = 0U;
unsigned int line_number = 0U;
while (in.get(c))
{
  ++character_count;
  if (c == '\n')
  {
    ++line_number;
  // Optional:
  // character_count = 0U;
  }
}
```

Note:  the expression `in>>c` will skip white spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that if I use myIn >> noskipws before my priming read it doesn't skip them, and read to \n character.

Answer (score 0):

Add counters for the character and line, which yoyu increase manually in the while loop.

Comment: @Crazypete3: Welcome to stackoverflow. Don't forget to give points for the answers you liked and mark one as the "correct" one, i.e. the one that helped you the most.

Comment: @Crazypete3 use the arrows left of the answers for positive and negative points. I see that you already marked the best answer as correct ;)

Comment: @ReazMurshed my code example would exactly look like ThomasMatthews answer which was posted a minute after mine. Please refer to that answer.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I did not critique or requested clarification, as the question was clear to me. How is this not an answer?

Comment: Sorry, didn't find any suitable option to clarify my review there. But the answer needs proper code example like the answer which is marked as excepted. Your answer can go as a comment which I wanted to tell actually.